# Problemas al cargar un proceso escrito en php mediante dominio con certificado SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, certificado-ssl

Hola buen dia a todos.

> Características de la instancia
>
> Ubuntu: **19.04**
>
> PHP: **7.2.24**
>
> Apache2: **2.4.38**

Estoy teniendo un problema al ejecutar un proceso en php

Si lo ejecuto desde la ip publica del servidor Ej. 192.168.0.1/proceso.php tarda unos 10 min en procesar y realizar la tarea

Pero si lo ejecuto con https://dominio.com/proceso.php a los 3 minutos me regresa un error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando https://dominio.com/ no se traba y trabaja de manera normal solo que cuando quiero ejecutar ese proceso no me lo termina.

Ya verifique los logs de apache y no veo nada que pueda ocasionar la falla.

Me gustaría recibir su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Tu dominio está correctamente configurado? ¿DNS?¿IPs?

Comment: El tiempo de ejecución máximo predeterminado para web es de 30 segundos y no tiene límite desde la línea de comandos. Prueba dando 15 minutos con `set_time_limit(60*15);` al inicio de tu script.

Comment: @Sal Realice ese ajuste solo para mi "proceso.php" y sigue teniendo el mismo problema.

No se por donde mas buscar, ya vi mi archivo php.ini y mi archivo apache2.conf. Alguna otra idea

Comment: ¿De casualidad es con cPanel/WHM? Prueba con otro browser queno sea chrome y coméntanos.